# Getting ReferenceError: HTMLInputElement is not defined with Angular 4 Universal

Tags: node.js, angular, universal

I have an app running on Angular 4 that I'm running on CDN. I'm trying to port it to Angular Universal because Google crawler isn't doing a very good job crawling my site. I'm running into the below error when trying to run my Node server script,

```
@ViewChild('text') text: HTMLInputElement;
```

ReferenceError: HTMLInputElement is not defined

I think it has to do with the Node engine not knowing what HTMLInputElement is, because it is native to the browser. Is there anyway I can import that or add a package so Node would recognize that?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know much about this, but will it work if you try setting type of the text variable to `any` and calling it with `text.nativeElement` ?

Answer (score 1):

Probably to late, but just to answer this question, you should use

`@ViewChild('text') text: ElementRef;`

and

`import { ElementRef } from '@angular/core';`